# jQuery location picker Google map showing grey color areas when displaying inside toggling form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I am creating a form with 3 steps and I have placed **jquery location picker** map inside the 3rd step, but on the starting, it will be hidden.

[Here is the link to the **javascript**](http://logicify.github.io/jquery-locationpicker-plugin/)

[here is the link to the page having issue:](http://yenino.envose.com/page/list_your_business)

but when user click next button goes to the next step by changing display property in style. But when we reach the step having this map, getting a blank grayish screen, but when I inspect the section having the map, the suddenly came back to normal. I have tried different methods like reinitializing of the map inside the next button action, reinitializing using callback function from google map javascript. But nothing is working out.

But the map and location picker works fine with normal forms without steps.

This is the html code i have used:-

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div id="address_location" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address_location_input" placeholder="Location" name="address_location" >
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="location_lat" name="location_lat">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="location_long" name="location_long">
</div>
```

This is the javascript I have used.

```
$('#address_location').locationpicker({
            location: {latitude:0 , longitude:0},   
            radius: 300,
            zoom: 15,
            enableAutocompleteBlur: false,                  
            inputBinding: {
            latitudeInput: $('#location_lat'),
            longitudeInput:$('#location_long'),
            radiusInput: $('#us2-radius'),
            locationNameInput: $('#address_location_input')
            },
            enableAutocomplete: true
            });
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue (pictures aren't very useful for debugging code...)

Comment: Hi geocodezip, i have edited my quesion, please have a look

Comment: Please provide the [mcve] **in the question itself**, not (just) links to external sites.

Comment: When/where are you calling the posted code? If you call it before the `<form>` is rendered in the DOM, it won't do anything useful.

Comment: While the map container div is hidden, it has zero width and height.

Answer (score -1):

The hidden div is likely returning 0 width.  Try running the map code only once the div is visible (has width).  Alternatively, run this after the div is visible: `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');`

Comment: I am using http://logicify.github.io/jquery-locationpicker-plugin/ plugin and when i am using this code i am getting error

Comment: You didn't mention that in the question. The code above assumed a standard map integration. I think you still need to load the map div once it's visible.  Or call the 'autosize' method defined in the Using Widget in Modal section of the link.

Comment: Hi sideroxylon, i have corrected my quesion, could you please check it again?

Comment: Have you tried calling `autosize` once the div is visible, as per the documentation?